# odoo Model id reserved column not created

Tags: postgresql, odoo, odoo-8

I am creating a table from my Model, but the field name 'id' is not creating.
The code is as below:

```
from opener import models, fields

class other_class(models.Model) : 
      {this is other table columns}    

class Test(models.Model):
      _name = 'stock.location.product.rel'

      location_id = fields.Many2one('stock.location','Location',required=True,ondelete="cascade")
      product_id = fields.Many2one('product.product','Product',required=True,ondelete="cascade")
```

Now when i run it, the table " stock_location_product_rel" is created, but only the columns ( location_id, product_id, create_uid, create_date, write_uid, write_date) I don't see the column named 'id'

I even tried using (osv.osv), it does't worked.

Thanks,

### UPDATE :

I used the same code but with different table name , then it worked ? can someone explain me ?

The code working is:

```
class Test(models.Model):
      _name = 'stock.location.product'

      location_id = fields.Many2one('stock.location','Location',required=True,ondelete="cascade")
      product_id = fields.Many2one('product.product','Product',required=True,ondelete="cascade")
```

I only removed .rel ?

## UPDATE:2

I created many2many field on product table and location table, which created the table automatically (stock.location.product.rel), and then created class to access this, again no id column.

Please Help

Comment: what happens when you run `select id from stock_location_product` ? from `psql`

Comment: Hi danidee, the error id " Column id does not exists"

Comment: if you don't have important information in the table, remove the table and then upgrade the module for odoo to recreate it from scratch again...because as far as i know the id (primary key) is automatically handled by odoo you don't need to manually do it

Answer (score 0):

Try writing the class which lacks 'id' first and then other class. It worked in my case.
If that doesn't work, try renaming your table with _table.